# Не войти в gii

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день. У меня возникла такая проблема - начал работать с фреймворком Yii. Установил через командную строку, все как положено. Первый раз все было нормально - все открывалось и работало (имею в виду модуль gii). А вот сейчас он напрочь отказывается работать, вместо этого, когда пытаюсь войти, пишет такую ошибку -

> `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\OpenServer\domains\yii-blog\protected\config\main.php:1).`

P.S. В файле конфигурации модуль подключил, пароль написал, вхожу через `http://yii-blog/index.php?r=gii`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема, ибо на форумах фреймворка ничего не помогло.

Comment: вам нужно не фрейморк учить, а основы пхп...

Comment: файл main.php в студию

Comment: согласен)) Проблемы вывода заголовков. кстати какая кодировочка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` - появляется из-за того, что вы посылаете заголовки после того как отправили содержание страницы. В остальном разбирайтесь и да, с основ было бы не плохо

Читать это по теме: [Решение проблемы "Cannot add header information - headers already sent"](http://www.phpfaq.ru/headers).

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в файле main.php у Вас есть работа с сессиями или cookies. Если у Вас в начале стоит session_start() , то удостоверьтесь, что перед этим не выводится другой текст(даже пробел). 
Либо у Вас такая же проблема с setCookie. 
В общем лучше покажите начало файла сюда и Вам подскажут.